# react-native android error: package does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react-native and I have to do the support on an app.
I can’t compile it on Android. I get an error while building it either by command line or from the android studio.

My configuration :

```
    $ react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
(node:21418) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
System:
    OS: Linux 5.15 Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    CPU: (8) x64 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz
    Memory: 228.16 MB / 7.68 GB
    Shell: 5.0.17 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.21.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.2/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.2/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.17 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.2/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 30, 33, 33
      Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.1
      System Images: android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-33 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.17 - /lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: ^10.1.0 => 10.1.0 
    react: ^18.1.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.70.6 => 0.70.6 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

The command line  :

> react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug --appId com.< app name>.staging

Error that I get :

```
> Task :app:compileStagingDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

    359 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 353 up-to-date
    <myProject root path>/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:99: error: package com.< app name>.staging does not exist
          new CodePush(com.< app name>.staging.BuildConfig.CODEPUSH_KEY, this.getApplication(), com.< app name>.staging.BuildConfig.DEBUG),
```

react-native.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    // disable autolinking for these unsupported libraries
    // @codepush
    'react-native-code-push': {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          packageImportPath: 'import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;',
          packageInstance:
            'new CodePush(BuildConfig.CODEPUSH_KEY, this.getApplication(), BuildConfig.DEBUG)',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I hope someone can help me!